# When creating a native Rust wallet on device how does one secure the wallet file?

Tags: wallet

I found a nice link, https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/sdk/src/signer, to resources for creating native Rust wallets, but how does one secure the wallet file on device? This is for desktop devices not mobile.

If anyone is using local file encryption please let me know what you're using and any links to docs and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the file readable only for a specific OS user, so it cannot be read by other users.

You can make sure it's not stored in directory where others might look for keys, and not in a directory that is auto-synced to a service like Dropbox.

Other than that, the file is just as secure (or vulnerable) as any other file on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard encryption format for "file wallets".  They are stored in plain text (raw ed25519 keypair encoded as a JSON integer array).  This is mainly because their primary use is via the CLI tools which have no notion of a "session" so they would have to be unlocked for every invocation that needs to sign.

The types you specify aren't strictly required to work in the default manner with respect to storage though. Anyone developing a an application where encryption would be appropriate can implement it as they see fit. Web wallets for instance, do encrypt key material (bip39 mnemonic rather than raw keypair) before storing it in site session data. Sollet does it [here](https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet/blob/ef996b5265dd45f5bcae70c00195c2de37d17628/src/utils/wallet-seed.js#L116-L201). JS, not Rust, but trivial to implement in most languages